# DocuSign.Core is not compatible with net60 (.net 6 version)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, docusignapi, asp.net-core-6.0, docusignconnect

I am upgrading .net core 3.1 to 6, DocuSign.Core 1.1.0.2 is not compatible with net60.

Error is:
***NU1202: Package DocuSign.Core 1.1.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package DocuSign.Core 1.1.0.2 supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)***

[image]

in Nuget package description also written same , any other solution or we need find another package for Docusign.

Answer (score 0):

That NuGet is quite old. You can use [Docusign
.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll) for .net core 6 compatibility